# How do you pass Knife a config file and pem key via command line?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I want to run Knife in my CICD server to upload cookbooks.

I run ephemeral slave so creating a static directory with all the files in the place knife expects by default would be impossible or painful (to write out that structure every time the container slave runs).

Can I pass the Knife command a knife.rb config as text and also a pem file as args?

I'm trying to use the `--config-option` but Knife is still demanding a configuration file:

```
knife status \
--config-option log_level=:info \
--config-option log_location=STDOUT \
--config-option node_name="myadminuser" \
--config-option client_key="admin.pem" \
--config-option chef_server_url="https://myserver.com/organizations/myorg"
```

get error:

```
WARNING: No knife configuration file found. See https://docs.chef.io/config_rb/ for details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
        25: from /bin/knife:360:in `<main>'
        24: from /bin/knife:360:in `load'
        23: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-16.3.45/bin/knife:24:in `<top (required)>'
        22: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-16.3.45/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:163:in `run'
        21: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-16.3.45/lib/chef/knife.rb:228:in `run'
        20: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-16.3.45/lib/chef/knife.rb:469:in `configure_chef'
        19: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-config-16.3.45/lib/chef-config/config.rb:134:in `apply_extra_config_options'
        18: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-config-16.3.45/lib/chef-config/config.rb:134:in `inject'
        17: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-config-16.3.45/lib/chef-config/config.rb:134:in `each'
        16: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/chef-config-16.3.45/lib/chef-config/config.rb:146:in `block in apply_extra_config_options'
        15: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:360:in `safe_load'
        14: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in `accept'
        13: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        12: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in `visit'
        11: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:313:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
        10: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:32:in `accept'
         9: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
         8: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:16:in `visit'
         7: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:123:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Scalar'
         6: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:60:in `deserialize'
         5: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb:74:in `tokenize'
         4: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/class_loader.rb:82:in `symbolize'
         3: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/class_loader.rb:32:in `symbolize'
         2: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/class_loader.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClassLoader>'
         1: from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in `load'
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/class_loader.rb:97:in `find': Tried to load unspecified class: Symbol (Psych::DisallowedClass)
```

Comment: The `--config-option OPTION=VALUE` allows you to "Override a single configuration option", so perhaps you should point at an (empty?) config file with `--config`?

Answer (score 0):

since the knife configuration is usually a one-time setup, there is not need to configure it each time or dynamically.

rather, you can have your [knife configuration (`knife.rb` or `client.rb`)](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_setup/) placed in [`.chef` directory in your chef repository (`.chef/knife.rb`)](https://docs.chef.io/chef_repo/)

plus, since the configurations are written in ruby, you can use environment variable in the configurations.

if you have multiple knife configurations, use [`knife-spork` to switch between them](https://github.com/jonlives/knife-spork)

Comment: as stated in my post, my use case is CICD with container slaves- this is how all modern cicd systems work. I also have dev and prod environments which requires dynamic configuration

Comment: create your knife\client configuration dynamically (or use environment variables), then use knife-spork to use the needed configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like - create (`touch`) a dummy `config.rb` file, followed by passing all the options with `--config-option`.

Example:

```
touch config.rb; \
knife status \
--config config.rb
--config-option log_level=:info \
--config-option log_location=STDOUT \
--config-option node_name="myadminuser" \
--config-option client_key="admin.pem" \
--config-option chef_server_url="https://myserver.com/organizations/myorg"
```